# Calculate the integral $\int\frac{dx}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I would like to solve the integral:
$$\int\frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}dx$$
How I do this kind of integrals?

Can you give me any tips?

Comment: this is not true $$(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$$

Comment: sorry missed it

Comment: i would make the substitution $$x+1=t$$ then we have $$dx=dt$$

Comment: One could let $u=(x-a)/\sqrt{1+x+x^2}$ for some suitable $a$. Perhaps $a=1$ would be fine. I don't have time to investigate it further now, so I only leave this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**just a hint**

$$x^2+x+1=(x+1/2)^2+3/4$$

put $$x+1/2=\sqrt {3}/2\sinh (t) $$

and then
$$u=\tanh (t/2) $$

Comment: I would prefer to not use sinh and tanh cause I am not used to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not comfortable with hyperbolic functions you could always use trigonometric ones.

Following @Salahaman_ Fatima hint one would have, on completing the square first

$$x^2 + x + 1 = \left (x + \frac{1}{2} \right )^2 + \frac{3}{4},$$
setting
$$x + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \tan \theta,$$
then
$$t = \tan (\theta/2).$$

Answer (score 0):

The Euler substitution $\sqrt{x^2+x+1}= xt+1$ is usually a reliable path

\begin{align}
&\int\frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}dx\\
=& \int\frac2{t(2-t)}dt=\ln |\frac t{t-2}|=-\ln |1-\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}-1}|
\end{align}